# What does "that" mean at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: which-that, that

"**That** which is certain is of no interest."

Above sentence starts with a "that", which I am curious about the meaning it adds. Would anybody please explain it?

Comment: This is a real demonstrative pronoun, not a complementizer or a relative pronoun. It means 'the one' and _that which is certain_ is a way to say 'anything which is certain'. Another way to say this is to form a headless relative clause, combining 'that which' into _what_ (a wh-word that can't otherwise be used as a relative pronoun): _What is certain is of no interest._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function of 'That' in your sentence is to refer to any thing that your sentence could apply to. So if I say 'That which doesn't kill me only makes me stronger' means '*Whatever doesn't kill me, makes me stronger*'.

You could even write the same as '*Anything which is certain is of no interest*'.

Answer (score 1):

It means *Anything which is certain is of no interest.* I.e. if something is certain then it is necessarily of no interest.

The construction *that which ...* (meaning *anything which ...*) has a slightly old-fashioned ring to it, although it's by no means obsolete. It's usually found it stock phrases, e.g.:

*That which doesn't kill us makes us stronger.*

In certain circumstances, you could replace *that which* with *what*, e.g.

*What doesn't kill us makes us stronger.*